# show tracked object in Video using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, video, ffmpeg

I am extending an existing OpenGL project with new functionality.

I can play a video stream using OpenGL with FFMPEG.
Some objects are moving in the video stream. Co-ordinates of those objects are know to me.

I need to show tracking of motion for that object, like continuously drawing a point or rectangle around the object as it moves on the screen.

Any idea how to start with it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use OpenGL for this task? Usually for computer vision algorithms, like motion tracking one uses OpenCV. In this case you could simply use the drawing functions of OpenCV as documented [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle).

If you are using OpenGL you might have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152683/how-to-change-single-texel-in-opengl-texture) because in this case I guess you draw the frames as textures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sigroad. Yeah, I have to do it in OpenGL. 
I collect object motion information using motion tracking algorithms. After that the video stream will be played in an OpenGL based video player (already developed and I am extending it). I need to show the motion tracking on the video while it is being played.

I am still working on understanding how video stream co-ordinates[640x480] will be translated to openGL co-ordinated[-1,1]
any further idea on how to do it?

Comment: Without seeing the relevant parts of the code I can't help too much and I am not an OpenGL expert. But I guess you are binding the frame as a texture to some quad, etc. In this case texture coordinates are [0,1]x[0,1] so (x,y) frame coordinates would be translated to (x/640,y/480) _texture_ coordinates. The OpenGL coordinates are almost independent of this, they are in connection with the coordinates of your polygon to which you have bound your texture.