# Overwrite pixel per pixel in an openGL 2d texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, pixel

I want to create an openGL 2D texture and set the RGBA values of every pixel by its own. Can someone give me an explanation for my problem? I didn't find one in the internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change single texel in OpenGL texture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152683/how-to-change-single-texel-in-opengl-texture)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to write the pixels of a 2D texture, you can simply use glTexImage2D, which takes a buffer specifying the pixel data you wish to upload to the texture (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml). Alternatively, you can use glTexSubImage2D to write a portion of the texture's pixels (https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml). If you're instead looking to do the analogous thing with the framebuffer, you can use glDrawPixels (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml).

If the target is the backbuffer, attempting to draw to a exact pixel values to a texture by binding it as a framebuffer, and then rendering a textured quad completely covering it is possible. However, this process is subject to blending and potentially pixel-center issues, whereas glDrawPixels is not.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this some time ago, when playing around with OpenGL.

Have a look at the code [here, on GitHub](https://github.com/rubikonx9/ColorfulGameOfLife).
You can find it in `main.cpp`.

Basically, my idea was to create an array of floats, set the values, copy to GPU with `glBufferData` and draw with `glDrawElements`.

As I remember it, doing it often was very bad in terms of performance, so it's probably not the best direction.

Please also note that this code is just my sandbox, and may not be the best possible example to be copied.